# A topology defined on collections of open covers of a topological $X$.

Tags: general-topology

Is anyone familiar with a topology which is defined on collections of open covers of a topological space $(X,O)$?

I am trying to define a topology induced by a linear ordering of the open covers, which is defined as $\mathcal U_1 \leq \mathcal U_2$ iff $U_2$ is a refinement of $U_1$.

In general, I was interested in the influence of such a topology on the behaviour of special kinds of covers, $\gamma$-covers for instance. For example, is the subspace containing $\gamma$-covers, closed in such a topology.

An open cover $\mathcal U$ of $X$ s called a $\gamma$-cover iff it is infinite and for each $x \in X$, the set $\{ U \in \mathcal U | x \in U \}$ is finite.

Thank you!

Comment: The discrete topology? The trivial topology? A topology induced by an arbitrary linear ordering of the open covers? You _must_ make your question more specific. Are there properties that you are looking to reflect from $X$ into this new space? Why are you interested in this?

Comment: You can put any topology you like on any set. Perhaps you are asking if there is a particularly "natural" topology on this set?

Comment: I see. Thank you I have added detailes to my question.

Comment: Shir, the refinement order is not a linear order. Consider in a metric space the cover by all balls of radius $\frac1n$ when $n$ is odd and the cover by all balls of radius $\frac1n$ when $n$ is even. Each refines the other, but they are not equal. Moreover, it's not necessarily linear, how can you assure that given two open covers one of them refines the other?